# ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKpjG.png)

I don't have any idea how to solve this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKpjG.png)

Comment: This is an image add some code and your input's what you tried till now.

Comment: Provide code to better understand, but this is maybe react version issue. project some packages are support old version.

Comment: i tried nothing as i dont know what to try to solve this

Comment: Your dep has a dep of its own that requires react 18, but you are using react 17. If you don’t care then do npm install —legacy-peer-deps.